# Network gear scripts

Tags: javascript

As a long time network engineer, Javascript has been a challenge to say the least. I am looking to use HTML & Javascript to create a template used to make network gear configurations. The HTML portion is very basic. Just a form with input fields and a button:

```
<body>
<form id="form1">
  <label for="siteCode">Site Code: </label>
  <input type="text" id="siteCode" name="name" placeholder="ex. HEN" required="required"/><br>
```

A button is used to call a Javascript function named "makeConfig"

I am running into an issue when it tries to get the "siteCode" ID from the HTML:

```
var siteCode = document.getElementById("siteCode");

function makeConfig() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=1000,height=850");

    myWindow.document.write("service nagle<br>no service pad<br>service tcp-keepalives-in<br>service tcp-keepalives-out<br>");

    myWindow.document.write("service timestamps debug datetime localtime show-timezone<br>service timestamps log datetime localtime show-timezone");

    myWindow.document.write("service password-encryption<br>service compress-config<br>!<br>");

    myWindow.document.write("hostname P" + siteCode + "A01M01UAA<br>!<br>");
}
```

The last line always generates a `null` value for `siteCode`. I would think this is simple, but I am drawing a blank. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Please post the location of your script tag in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`siteCode` will be a reference to the DOM (Document Object Model) node of the element; which contains a bunch of objects and properties that you probably don't want to print.

Instead; you probably want the the text that the user has entered into it. For that; you could do something like

```
myWindow.document.write("hostname P" + siteCode.value + "A01M01UAA<br>!<br>");
```

Notice we are getting it's value (`siteCode.value`); rather than just the raw element.

---

For something like this; another common mistake is that the JavaScript may be running before the rest of the page has loaded; and therefore the element may simply not have loaded yet. However, since you've put it in a function; I'm assuming that's not what happening here; and you're running it only when the user presses a button; etc. If not; that may be something to check.